# Get array with all values for certain key in JSON wih JQ

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

Say I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "a": 0,
  "b": "c",
  "d": {
    "e": {
      "f": "g",
      "comments": {
        "leading": "Lorem ipsum"
      },
      "h": {
        "i": {
          "j": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        },
        "comments": {
          "trailing": "dolor sit"
        }
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      "leading": "amet."
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get an array with the values of all the fields named `comments` (which can be nested in any level). So, in this case I want to get:

```json
[
  {
    "leading": "Lorem ipsum"
  },
  {
    "trailing": "dolor sit"
  },
  {
    "leading": "amet."
  }
]
```

The order of the array doesn't matter.

How can this be achieved with `jq`? I have only performed basic stuff with it and haven't been able to produce anything close to what I need.

Thanks in advance ☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getpath` function. Use `paths` to identify all the paths leading upto `.comments` and get the paths' value

```
jq '[ getpath ( paths | select( .[-1] == "comments" ) ) ]'
```

Or use a recursive descent to filter objects containing `.comments` and get its value

```
jq '[ recurse | select(has("comments")?).comments ]'
```

Comment: Works great! Thaks a lot ❤️